# ¿Cómo hacer que se hereden las variables internas a una clase hija y cambiarlas?

Tags: java, funciones, clase-anidada

Tengo 2 clases Tamagotchi que es padre y pájaro que es hija. Las variables internas del Tamagotchi son privadas. Esta es la función de vivir de la clase padre Tamagotchi:

```
public void vivir(Tamagotchi orig){
       this.setDiversion(diversion+=-5);
       this.setSueño(sueño+=-5);
       this.setHambre(hambre+=-5);
       this.setHigiene(higiene+=-5);
   }
```

---

Y esta es la misma función pero en la clase hija pájaro:

```
public void vivir(Tamagotchi orig){
       //Atributos padre diversion, hambre, sueño no emtram

  this.setVuelo(vuelo+=-5);
   }
```

En el main al llamar la función solo me está restando la variable vuelo pero no las otras, sin embargo si quito la función hija si me resta las variables internas del padre.

¿Cómo hago para que se resten las dos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema está en el planteamiento mismo de tus clases. Eso se intuye con sólo ver que a `vivir()` le pasas en parámetro una objeto del tipo `Tamagotchi`. ¿Por qué, si el método, como dices más arriba, es parte de la misma clase `Tamagotchi`?

Además, el hecho mismo de que `vivir()` deba estar en ambas clases o en una de ellas es discutible. Las clases son entidades que representan objetos de la vida (o de la muerte) *real* en cualquiera de sus estados. Parecería que `vivir()` pertenecería a un contexto que es parte de la lógica de tu aplicación y por tanto debería implementarse en ese contexto, no dentro de la clase. ¿Por qué? Porque si se trabaja con objetos `Pajaro` o `Tamagotchi` que **ya no viven**, el método `vivir()` sobraría en esos casos. O sea, una clase así no representa la realidad total del objeto. Pero dejemos eso para otro debate.

El principio de *herencia* en Java es muy simple:

1. El padre debe tener un constructor que recibiría todos los miembros que le son propios.
2. El hijo debe tener también un constructor que recibirá todos los miembros que son suyos, **y también los del padre**. En ese constructor, por una parte **el hijo pasa al padre, con `super()` todos los elementos del padre** y por otra **setea los que son suyos**.

Eso es lo básico de la herencia. Si lo haces así no tendrás mayores problemas. En cuanto al método `vivir()` (aunque insisto en que no debería ser parte de ninguna de las dos clases), si lo quieres mantener allí, haces lo mismo que explicamos en (2). Tienes que poner el método en las dos clases. Luego, invocas a `super.vivir()` para que haga las operaciones con los miembros suyos y, en el hijo, haces la operación con el miembro `vuelo`.

Es todo, no hay más misterio.

Vamos a ver un ejemplo de las clases:

### Clase padre

```
public class Tamagotchi 
{

    protected int diversion;
    protected int sleep; //Ver nota 1 sobre este cambio
    protected int hambre; 
    protected int higiene; 
    /*
        Cuando invoques al super() desde el hijo 
        la instancia del hijo se llenará con estos datos
    */
    public Tamagotchi(int diversion, int sleep, int hambre, int higiene ) 
    {
        this.diversion = diversion;
        this.sleep = sleep;
        this.hambre = hambre;
        this.higiene = higiene;
    }

    /*Getters*/
    // ...

    public void setDiversion(int diversion) 
    {
        this.diversion = diversion;
    }        

    public void setSleep(int sleep) 
    {
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }        

    public void setHambre(int hambre) 
    {
        this.hambre = hambre;
    }        

    public void setHigiene(int higiene) 
    {
        this.higiene = higiene;
    }        

    public void vivir()
    {
           diversion -= 5;
           sleep -= 5;
           hambre -=5;
           higiene -=5;
    }


}
```

### Clase hija

```
public class Pajaro extends Tamagotchi 
{

    private int vuelo;

    public Pajaro(int diversion, int sleep, int hambre, int higiene, int vuelo) 
    {
        /*
            Aquí le pasas al padre los miembros propios de él
            y dejas en el hijo el miembro vuelo que no está en el padre
        */
        super(diversion, sleep, hambre, higiene);
        this.vuelo = vuelo;
    }

    /*Getters*/
    // ...

    public void setVuelo(int vuelo) 
    {
        this.vuelo = vuelo;
    }

    public void vivir()
    {
      /*Aquí invocas el método vivir()  del padre*/  
      super.vivir();
      /*Y operas el valor propio del hijo como hicimos en el constructor*/  
      vuelo -=5;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return String.format("diversión: %d, sueño: %d, hambre: %d, higiene: %d, vuelo: %d",
                         this.diversion,this.sleep,this.hambre,this.higiene,this.vuelo);
    }        

}
```

### Prueba

Hagamos una prueba cualquiera:

```
    Pajaro mPajaro = new Pajaro(10,20,30,40,50);
    mPajaro.vivir();
    System.out.println(mPajaro.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
diversión: 5, sueño: 15, hambre: 25, higiene: 35, vuelo: 45
```

---

### DEMO

Aquí tienes una **[<kbd>DEMOSTRACIÓN</kbd>](https://rextester.com/ALC32392)** en línea para hacer pruebas sobre el código.

---

**Notas:**

1. Notarás que me he tomado la libertad de cambiar el nombre del miembro `sueño` por `sleep`. Esta es una opción personal, sólo para indicar que no es recomendable usar palabras acentuadas o `ñ` en la convención de nombre. Si en algún contexto hay algún problema de codificación tu variable `sueño` podría producir insomnio :-) Es cierto que esto es menos probable en contextos modernos, pero nunca se sabe, sobre todo en el pasado hubo problemas con eso. En la comunidad de programadores de hecho se recomienda implementar una convención de nombre en inglés, porque es menos problemática para cualquier codificación al no usar acentos ni caracteres especiales, es más sencilla y más elegante, porque generalmente los sustantivos/verbos son más cortos (por ejemplo `getAll()` vs `obtenerTodos()`, `addCompany()` vs `añadirCompañia()`, etc) y la internacionalización del código o el trabajo en equipo es mucho más comprensible para todos (por ejemplo un programador en China, uno en Japón, uno en España, uno en Italia, uno en Inglaterra y otro en Brasil).

Comment: Yo, además, intentaría evitar la llamada  `this.setDiversion(diversion+=-5);`, que crea confusión y puede no ser trivial entender lo que realmente está haciendo y pasando en esas asignaciones, y lo cambiaría directamente por un `this.setDiversion(diversion - 5);` o, mejor aún, un `diversion -= 5;`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia totalmente de acuerdo contigo. He actualizado el código aplicando tu sabia sugerencia. Gracias por el dato.

Comment: Me parece que, además de lo que dice @OscarGarcia, por el simple hecho de una buena práctica de programación, habría que agregar el modificador de acceso ```protected``` a los campos de la clase Padre, (dejando de lado la implementación de setters y getters). Simplemente para que el concepto de herencia esté más completo aún de lo que ya está con tu respuesta. No digo que sea imprescindible... Sólo es una acotación. ¿Qué opinan?

Comment: @Akamai en realidad no poner modificar y poner `protected` es lo mismo, [como indica la doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) (ver tabla). Aunque sí, es mejor poner las cosas de forma explícita.

Comment: No es lo mismo, a nivel subclase -como en éste caso- es totalmente distinto; de hecho con eso se arregla el problema.

Comment: Tienes razón @Sal. Ahora modifico. ¿Qué quieres decir con *«con eso se arregla el problema»*?

Comment: Si el atributo es *protegido*, puede hacer `diversion+=-5` desde la subclase.

Comment: Mucha gracias@A.cedano y todos los demás. si, los constructores y otros métodos no los puse para ir al grano..  HE probado con lo de super.vivir() en las clases hijas y me ha funcionado. Soy bastante novato en esto...

Comment: Ok @sal entiendo ese punto, pero también si se declara sin modificador se podría acceder desde la clase hija. En mi opinión, si debería existir un método `vivir()` en las clases (con lo cual no estoy de acuerdo por lo dicho en la respuesta) debería estar en las dos y en ese caso es mejor (por motivos de claridad y de simplicidad) invocar el método de la clase padre para modificar a los miembros que le son propios, así se mantiene coherencia con lo que ocurre también en el constructor.